# Java HttpResponseBodyPart XML parsing error

Tags: java, asynchttpclient

I am facing below error while getting response from server.

```
org.jdom.input.JDOMParseException: Error on line 1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
at org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:468)
at org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:851)
```

while getting response I am getting below content.

```
content = ?<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

although file actual content is

```
content = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

the method that I have used is below

```
@Override
public State onBodyPartReceived(HttpResponseBodyPart bodyPart) throws Exception {
      System.out.println("onBodyPartReceived");
      content += new String(bodyPart.getBodyByteBuffer().array(), "UTF-8");
      return State.CONTINUE;
}
```

Comment: Maybe your XML file contains a BOM .

Comment: Are you sure content doesn't have a '?' before caling onBodyPartReceived(). Because you are appending to whatever is there from before.

Comment: Sugestion to debug: print what you receive before appending it to content. In that way you'll have a better understanding of your issue.

Comment: Yes, I am sure content doesn't have a '?' before caling onBodyPartReceived(). @Juan

Comment: @Arnaud Thank you for reply, It may be BOM(Byte Order Mark). But I dont want BOM in my content, Is there any proper way to get content without BOM, I dont want to use SubString method.